# Does a solution to a differential equation be able to have uncountable zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider the following dynamical system with a continuously differentiable function $f$ defined in some open region $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} x = f(x),\quad t\geq0,\quad x(0)=0. $$
Due to the Cauchy-Lipschitz theory, we have a (continuously differentiable) solution $x(t)$ on an interval $[0,\varepsilon)$. Let's denote its zero set by $Z_f=\{~t>0:x(t)=0\}$ and assume that
$$
x\not\equiv0~(t\geq0),\quad |Z_f|\geq 1.
$$
Under these settings, is it possible to hold the following?
$$ \inf\{~t>0: x(t)=0\}>0.$$
To argue the above inequality, I think there should be additional information. (e.g. the solution should be analytic.) Because the solution $x$ may be a function with uncountable zero like [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83970/on-the-uncountability-of-zero-sets). Is there a way to exclude such pathological functions?

If I have the wrong knowledge, please let me know with some reference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $x(t_n)=0$ for some sequence $t_n\downarrow0$, then $x(0)=0=x’(0)$. By the uniqueness of the Cauchy problem, we get $x\equiv0$.

Comment: @Feng Thanks for your comment. I understood that $x'(0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x(t_n)}{t_n}=0$. However, I don't understand your second sentence. First, how can I use the condition $x'(0)=0$ to conclude $x\equiv 0$? Second, I excluded the case $x\equiv0$ so you mean my situation was wrong?

Comment: Assume that $x$ is a solution to $x’=f(x)$ with $x(0)=0=x’(0)$, then we must have $f(0)=0$. In this case, it is clear that $x_1\equiv0$ is a solution to the Cauchy problem $x’=f(x), x(0)=0$. By the uniqueness of solution, we have $x=x_1$, hence $x\equiv0$. I’m here to prove that if $x$ is a non-zero solution to $x’=f(x)$ with $x(0)=0$, then we cannot have $\inf\{t>0: x(t)=0\}=0$.

Comment: @Feng Oh.. I understood. Thank you! Also, then a function with uncountable zero cannot be a solution. Right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Every uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ has a limit point, and then the above argument works.

Comment: @Feng Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  Sorry. Maybe I’m not getting your idea. Since $f(0)=0$, letting $x_1\equiv0$ we have $x_1’=0=f(0)=f(x_1)$, hence $x_1$ is a solution. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  I was proving that if $x$ is a solution of $x’=f(x)$ with $x(0)=0$ and $\inf\{t>0: x(t)=0\}=0$, then $x\equiv0$. It follows from $\inf\{t>0: x(t)=0\}=0$ that $x’(0)=0$. Now taking $t=0$ in the equation $x’(t)=f(x(t))$ gives that $0=x’(0)=f(x(0))=f(0)$, i.e., $f(0)=0$. After that, using the uniqueness we will show that $x\equiv0$. I’m not saying that $x\equiv0$ for ALL solutions, but it happens under the condition that $\inf\{t>0: x(t)=0\}=0$. I hope that everything is correct now.

Comment: Any solution of a scalar autonomous ODE is either constant or strictly monotonously increasing or decreasing. Thus there can not even be two zeros, except if the function is constant zero.